# Populate the cloud firestore document containing an array of document references

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named campgrounds in which every document contains an array of document reference to the documents in the comments collections.
It looks like this [Campground](https://ibb.co/hDd0kWV)

I'm trying to figure out a way to populate this comments array before sending it to my ejs template.

My code looks like this

```
app.get("/campgrounds/:docId", function(req, res) {
    var docRef = firestore.collection("campgrounds").doc(req.params.docId);

    try {
        docRef.get().then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                res.send("no such document");
            } else {
                // res.send(doc.data());
                res.render("campground", {
                    doc: doc.data(),
                    title: doc.data().title,
                    id: req.params.docId
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure this what you are looking for but simply with `doc.data().comments` you will get an array of the comments Refs.

Comment: How do I populate the comments using the document references so that they can be displayed on the template?

Answer (score 2):

In your array you store [`DocumentReferences`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference). If you want to get the data of the corresponding documents in order to include this data in your object you should use `Promise.all()` to execute the variable number (1 or more) of `get()` asynchronous operations.

The following should work (not tested at all however):

```
app.get("/campgrounds/:docId", function(req, res) {
var docRef = firestore.collection("campgrounds").doc(req.params.docId);

try {
    var campground = {};
    docRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            res.send("no such document");
        } else {
            campground = {
                doc: doc.data(),
                title: doc.data().title,
                id: req.params.docId
            };
            var promises = [];
            doc.data().comments.forEach((element, index) => {
                promises.push(firestore.doc(element).get());
            });
            return Promise.all(promises);
        }
    })
    .then(results => {
            var comments = {};
            results.forEach((element, index) => {
                comments[index] = element.data().title  //Let's imagine a comment has a title property
            });
            campground.comments = comments;
            res.render("campground", campground);
    })

} catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
   }
});
```

Note that with this code you are doing  1 + N queries (N being the length of the `comments` array). You could denormalize your data and directly store in the `campground` doc the data of the `comments`: you would then need only one query.